# Is there any way to control Windows Mobile (Win10 phone) from Win10 Desktop?

Tags: windows, mobile, windows-10, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I would like to control my windows mobile from desktop.
I'd like to have full access, keyboard and mouse as well.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: ask this on http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

If both of your devices support `Miracast` you can use the `Connect` app. Find more info on Windows Central [here](http://www.windowscentral.com/hands-project-pc-feature-windows-10-anniversary-update).

Edit: If you want to control your phone, just open the `Connect` app from your Action Center. This will work even for not Continuum enabled phones. You still have to enable the connection in Settings app on PC and you may have to pair the PC with the phone over the Bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is an app called PC remote, created by microsoft.
If that's something like what you're looking for: https://www.microsoft.com/da-dk/store/p/pc-remote/9wzdncrfhvwt.

Edit: Thats a Danish version, but I think you should be able to find an English version aswell.